# Weather Underground API: Querying API by IP

Tags: php, api, wunderground

I'm building a Weather class that is allowed to search by IP address. I am trying to implement the Wunderground API as one of the options to use. But, I can't seem to find a way to query the API with an IP address. I've tried this: `autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query={IP ADDRESS HERE}` -- but as you can see, it finds no results. Any tips on going about this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Does that API even support queries by IP address?

Comment: I can't seem to find documentation on it. If it does, great, I just need to know where to find it. If it doesn't, what would be a good way to build the query from an IP address?

Comment: To start with, i'm not sure that is an API open for public consumption. They do have an API, more info here [WU API](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/).  You need to do a lookup on the ip address and turn it into geographic information that WU can use. There are geo_ip databases available, but due to how IP addrs are assigned, its probably 90-95% accurate and it needs to be updated regularly.

Comment: Are you sure that you are going about this the right way? There is a huge site with details about their API: http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs

Comment: FYI: the API OP is referencing *is* documented: http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=autocomplete-api

Comment: Yes, it is documented. I thought I said that in the OP, guess I didn't, sorry. So I guess the only way is to use a GeoIP PHP class then? I'm using this class (http://pear.php.net/package/Net_GeoIP/) to get the country code's already, but I thought I'd ask to make sure I didn't miss something in the documentation, and ask for advice. I guess my question now would be what's the best GeoIP API/Class to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `http://api.wunderground.com/api/Your_Key/forecast/geolookup/conditions/q/autoip.json?geo_ip=Your_IP`, instead.

See link for more details: http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/index.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the World Weather Online API instead. It's easy to use, with a publicly facing JSON response that's easy to parse. All you need is to provide your API key with each query and it supports IP Address query, Latitude, Longitude, Locale name and others. Try it out man. Find it here [HERE](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/free-weather-feed.aspx)

Comment: Hi, I also use the World Weather Online API as a helper in my class. Basically, I'm building a class that relies on a helper, but returns the helpers values and does formatting and stuff from the main class. One of my helpers *is* the World Weather Online API, but sadly, it does not have as many options as Wunderground provides, which is what you'd expect from a free service anyway.